# What's wrong with this bubble sort implemtation

Tags: sorting, lua

I've asked a question about `sort` in Lua, despite  multiple suggestions I couldn't solve my issue so I've decide to implement bubble sort like :

```
local last_num = 0
local  channelTable={}
for num in channels.each_number() do -- channels.each_number()  returns each time a number 
    channelTable[last_num] =num;
    last_num = last_num +1;
end 
-- Bubblesort   
local a =0; 
for num=1, last_num-1 do 
    for a = 1,(last_num - num -1) do 
        if(channelTable[a]>channelTable[a+1]) then
            channelTable[a], channelTable[a+1]  = channelTable[a+1],channelTable[a];
        end
    end
end
```

the problem that I have is that the last element of `channelTable` get "lost" meaning  for example is I have  : 1 2 3 .... 13 14, I can't use the 14 value ? 
any idea what I'm doing wrong !

**UPDATE**

after rpattiso's suggestion here is the code update :

```
-- Bubble sort 
local n=#channelTable
local swapped = false
repeat 
    swapped = false
    for i= 2,n do 
        if( channelTable[i-1]> channelTable[i])then 
            channelTable[i-1],channelTable[i] = channelTable[i], channelTable[i+1];
            swapped =true 
        end 
    end 
until not swapped
```

I still get an error  @ : `swapped =true`
the error message is:

```
attempt to compare two nil values
```

Comment: You insert into `channelTable` starting at zero but sort it starting at one.

Comment: isn't the first element of  a table in Lua 1 ?

Comment: Yes, but you inserted your first element at index 0 in the first loop. Then loop `last_num - 1` times so you miss the first and last elements.

Comment: any idea how should I do it

Comment: sorry but I don't get it ?

Comment: Please take some time to indent your code properly.

Comment: @YuHao  I got your point !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables in Lua are 1-based and it looks like your using a 0-based implementation. Here is a very slightly modified version of the [bubblesort code in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) to be used with a 1-based table.

```
function bubbleSort(A)
  local n = #A
  local swapped = false
  repeat
    swapped = false
    for i=2,n do   -- 0 based is for i=1,n-1 do
      if A[i-1] > A[i] then
        A[i-1],A[i] = A[i],A[i-1]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  until not swapped
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but please check the update of the question

Comment: @Engine swap part is off, should be `channelTable[i-1],channelTable[i]=channelTable[i],channelTable[i-1]`. Probably best to just cut and paste this and use it like so `bubbleSort(channelTable)`